# How do I automatize changing the text style in Premiere Pro

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects, adobe-premiere

I have a transcribed video in Premiere Pro and I have a list of keywords that should be highlighted with their colors. I'm trying to automatize this process and not do it manually.

I've tried using extendScript but it seems like it can't change the color of a single word in a text layer, only the color of the whole text.
I've also tried linking the transcribed text to After Effects and to some things there too but couldn't figure out a solution.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!